# IBM Worklight -Getting error in LDAPLoginModule

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am working on LDAPLoginModule in Worklight v5.0.6.

In that application-descriptor.xml file I have included all the parameters they have given in the sample code provided by IBM.

However, I am getting an error:

> -80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09030B, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v893

I am also not finding parameters to specify `manager-dn` and `manager-password` in application-descriptor.xml.

Answer (score 2):

A 52e exception means invalid credentials (http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/18470.html). If by manager-dn/password, you are referring to a distinct user to bind to LDAP as, then it is not possible with the ldap login module (If you login as xxx, you will be bound to the ldap server as xxx).

If you are on liberty or WAS, you can use the LDAP features included with those systems to do a more advanced bind, by using the LTPA Login module instead.

Comment: Hi Mike,If I use SPRING Security framework I used to provide following LDAP manager credentials. Now I am not finding the same here. 
<security:ldap-server  url="ldap://xyzcompy.com:389/OU=India,DC=xyzcompy,DC=com" manager-dn="admn@xyzcompy.com"  manager-password="pass123"/> 
<security:ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}" group-search-filter="member={0}" group-search-base="OU=All Groups,OU=Bangalore" />

Answer (score 0):

it should be working for Active Directory, you don't need to have bindDN and bindPassword for it to work.
I think the magic is that, for the principalPattern, you should use the @LDAPDomain for the login

Comment: If I use SPRING Security framework I used to provide following LDAP manager credentials. Now I am not finding the same here. 
<security:ldap-server  url="ldap://xyzcompy.com:389/OU=India,DC=xyzcompy,DC=com" manager-dn="admn@xyzcompy.com"  manager-password="pass123"/> 
<security:ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}" group-search-filter="member={0}" group-search-base="OU=All Groups,OU=Bangalore" />